# How can I determine a Unicode character from its name in Python, even if that character is a control character?

Tags: python, unicode

I'd like to create an array of the Unicode code points which constitute white space in JavaScript (minus the Unicode-white-space code points, which I address separately).  These characters are horizontal tab, vertical tab, form feed, space, non-breaking space, and BOM.  I could do this with magic numbers:

```
whitespace = [0x9, 0xb, 0xc, 0x20, 0xa0, 0xfeff]
```

That's a little bit obscure; names would be better.  The `unicodedata.lookup` method passed through `ord` helps some:

```
>>> ord(unicodedata.lookup("NO-BREAK SPACE"))
160
```

But this doesn't work for 0x9, 0xb, or 0xc -- I think because they're control characters, and the "names" FORM FEED and such are just alias names.  Is there any way to map these "names" to the characters, or their code points, in standard Python?  Or am I out of luck?

Comment: How obscure -- if this is a one-off, globally constant list, can't you just write the number literals and put the Unicode name in a comment?

Comment: A comment would address the unreadability issue.  But it doesn't address the issue that the reader must accept on blind faith that the numbers are correct.  (Granted, some of these are pretty well-known, but that's not always going to be the case.)  I'll settle for commenting in the end if that's what it comes to, but if it's possible to avoid that, that seems better to me.

Comment: Why would that be a problem? The numbers *are* standardized after all. Do your clients fear that you would trick them somehow?

Comment: Not "trick", just make a mistake.  Perhaps it's an excess of concern, to be sure, but better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Kerrek SB's comment is a good one: just put the names in a comment.

BTW, Python also supports a named unicode literal:

```
>>> u"\N{NO-BREAK SPACE}"
u'\xa0'
```

But it uses the same unicode name database, and the control characters are not in it.

Answer (score 2):

You could roll your own "database" for the control characters by parsing a few lines of the UCD files in the Unicode [public directory](http://www.unicode.org/Public/6.1.0/ucd/).  In particular, see the [UnicodeData-6.1.0d3](http://www.unicode.org/Public/6.1.0/ucd/UnicodeData-6.1.0d3.txt) file (or see the parent directory for earlier versions).

Comment: This is brilliant: `0009;<control>;Cc;0;S;;;;;N;CHARACTER TABULATION;;;;`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it can be done in standard Python.  The [`unicodedata`](http://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html) module uses the [UnicodeData.txt v5.2.0](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/5.2.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt) Unicode database.  Notice that the control characters are all assigned the name `<control>` (the second field, semicolon-delimited).

The script `Tools/unicode/makeunicodedata.py` in the Python source distribution is used to generate the table used by the Python runtime.  The `makeunicodename` function looks like this:

```
def makeunicodename(unicode, trace):

    FILE = "Modules/unicodename_db.h"

    print "--- Preparing", FILE, "..."

    # collect names
    names = [None] * len(unicode.chars)

    for char in unicode.chars:
        record = unicode.table[char]
        if record:
            name = record[1].strip()
            if name and name[0] != "<":
                names[char] = name + chr(0)
    ...
```

Notice that it skips over entries whose name begins with `"<"`.  Hence, there is no name that can be passed to `unicodedata.lookup` that will give you back one of those control characters.

Just hardcode the code points for horizontal tab, line feed, and carriage return, and leave a descriptive comment.  As the [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) goes, "practicality beats purity".

Answer (score 1):

A few points:

(1) "BOM" is not a character. BOM is a byte sequence that appears at the start of a file to indicate the byte order of a file that is encoded in UTF-nn. BOM is u'\uFEFF'.encode('UTF-nn'). Reading a file with the appropriate codec will slurp up the BOM; you don't see it as a Unicode character. A BOM is not data. If you do see u'\uFEFF' in your data, treat it as a (deprecated) ZERO-WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE.

(2) "minus the Unicode-white-space code points, which I address separately"?? Isn't NO-BREAK SPACE a "Unicode-white-space" code point?

(3) Your Python appears to be broken; mine does this:

```
>>> ord(unicodedata.lookup("NO-BREAK SPACE"))
160
```

(4) You could use escape sequences for the first three.

```
>>> map(hex, map(ord, "\t\v\f"))
['0x9', '0xb', '0xc']
```

(5) You could use `" "` for the fourth one.

(6) Even if you could use names, the readers of your code would still be applying blind faith that e.g. "FORM FEED" is a whitespace character.

(7) What happened to to `\r` and `\n`?

Comment: JavaScript has some fairly bizarre legacy-compatibility particularities, some of it from being based on UCS-2 rather than the more-sensible UTF-16, some of it from people writing code that old engines happened to accept (wrongly or not) and which new engines must accept to have a chance at getting market share.  So we actually must treat random BOMs in the text of a script as whitespace.

Comment: For "minus the...", the JS spec is redundant in this way, so doing the same is reasonable for readability.  For "broken", I think I mis-copied from my console somehow (sorry about that), because I get the same 160 you do now.  For FF being whitespace, I expect the reader would compare to the JS spec to verify that.  For `\r\n`, the code does `if code in whitespace or code in lineterms` later, catching those in the process.

Comment: @Jeff Walden: As I said, "BOMs in  the text" don't happen. A `u'\uFEFF'` in your text is NOT a BOM. It should be treated as a ZERO-WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE, which is whitespace. Same outcome as you desire, just don't call it a BOM.

Comment: @Jeff Walden: "whitespace" and "lineterms" are not mutually exclusive. Good coding practice would suggest that you define them each properly, saving the credulous reader from having to read the whole code to find out why `\r` and `\n` are not included in your redefinition of whitespace.

Comment: The ECMAScript standard has the grammar rule `WhiteSpace:: <TAB> <VT> <FF> <SP> <NBSP> <BOM> <USP>` (that's an alternation, since I had to remove the line breaks), so whether it is or is not a BOM, in this context it seems best to call it a BOM even if it is not actually a "BOM".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're working with Unicode strings, the first five items in your list, plus all other Unicode space characters, will be matched by the `\s` option when using a regular expression. Using Python 3.1.2:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '\u0009,\u000b,\u000c,\u0020,\u00a0,\ufeff'
>>> s
'\t,\x0b,\x0c, ,\xa0,\ufeff'
>>> re.findall(r'\s', s)
['\t', '\x0b', '\x0c', ' ', '\xa0']
```

And as for the byte-order mark, the one given can be referred to as `codecs.BOM_BE` or `codecs.BOM_UTF16_BE` (though in Python 3+, it's returned as a `bytes` object rather than `str`).

Answer (score 0):

The [official Unicode recommendation](http://unicode.org/standard/reports/tr13/tr13-5.html) for newlines may or may not be at odds with the way the Python `codecs` module handles newlines.  Since `u'\n'` is often said to mean "new line", one might expect based on this recommendation for the Python string `u'\n'` to represent character `U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR` and to be encoded as such, rather than as the semantic-less control character `U+000A`.  But I can only imagine the confusion that would result if the `codecs` module actually implemented that policy, and there are valid counter-arguments besides.  Ditto for horizontal/vertical tab and form feed, which are probably not really characters but controls anyway.  (I would certainly consider backspace to be a control, not a character.)

Your question seems to assume that treating `U+000A` as a control character (instead of a line separator) is wrong; but that is not at all certain.  Perhaps it is more wrong for text processing applications everywhere to assume that a legacy printer-platen-scrolling control signal is really a true "line separator".

Answer (score -1):

You can extend the lookup function to handle the characters that aren't included.

```
def unicode_lookup(x):
    try:
        ch = unicodedata.lookup(x)
    except KeyError:
        control_chars = {'LINE FEED':unichr(0x0a),'CARRIAGE RETURN':unichr(0x0d)}
        if x in control_chars:
            ch = control_chars[x]
        else:
            raise
    return ch

>>> unicode_lookup('SPACE')
u' '
>>> unicode_lookup('LINE FEED')
u'\n'
>>> unicode_lookup('FORM FEED')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    unicode_lookup('FORM FEED')
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 3, in unicode_lookup
    ch = unicodedata.lookup(x)
KeyError: "undefined character name 'FORM FEED'"
```

Comment: -1 Quite apart from the fact that this is a longwinded way of writing something that doesn't overcome his "credibility with the reader" problem, you have your own credibility problem: `len(u'\x000a')` produces 3.

Comment: @John, thanks for catching that - I never would have guessed that unicode hex constants would be limited to two digits. I've completely replaced them with `unichr` calls. As for the credibility problem, there's really no way around it. If the standard library doesn't provide it, the best alternative is to provide a function that only has to be vetted once.

Comment: Still -1, for the first reason, plus `unichr(0x0a)` is preposterous obfuscation cpmpared with `u'\n'`

Comment: read the manual, don't guess. Unicode hex constants start with \x for one byte, \u for 2 bytes, and \U for 4 bytes. Best alternative is list of values with comments -- same amount of signal as your approach, but MUCH less noise.

Comment: @John, I respect your reasoning even if I don't agree with it. The `unichr(0x0a)` representation will be easier to check against the official Unicode tables, so I don't consider it an obfuscation.

Comment: @John, I've always found the Python documentation to be a bit lacking when you're looking for a specific feature, it's not indexed very well. With your prompting I was able to find the documentation for `\u` halfway down a very long page: http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code

Comment: documentation: try this, found exactly where one would expect it to be, without needing any index: http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals